# Gradle tweak/substitute logger configuration during testing?

Tags: java, logging, gradle, logback, slf4j

I'm using logback and SLF4J.

This might involve having a second file other than logback.xml file under src/main/resources (typically): does anyone know if there's a way of choosing a different xml file just when running a Gradle `Test`?  Or it might involve something programmatic.  Or some other technique using the build file.

I'm not really sure whether this is an SLF4J/logback or a Gradle question ... hopefully somebody with a lot more expertise than me in Gradle can help?

It's just that during testing I want to tweak a couple of things, e.g.:

1. prevent some STDERR messages (i.e. meant to be produced during
   tests) going to STDERR
2. curtail some stacktrace print-outs (which
   would be logged fully if the error occurred during an actual run). 
   It seems you can possibly do this by using Gradle's `TestLogging` class.

Comment: It feels like this would fall more under the realm of your app than of Gradle. What kind of app is it?

Comment: Thanks.. It's a simple app, using the CLI, to handle Lucene indexing. I'm still a beginner both with Gradle and with logback/SLF4J.  So I don't know what the options or best practices are.  Y'day I discovered that logback first looks for logback-test.xml and then logback.xml.  So I'm manually deleting the first when I "deploy" (copy files to a place where I use it for real)...

Answer (score 2):

Try putting logback-test.xml in your src/test/resources folder. You shouldn't even need to name it "-test"; that folder will be ahead of src/main/resources on the classpath.

Good luck.